# What is breaking my Process.StartInfo.OutputDataReceived callbacks prematurely?

Tags: c#, multithreading, process, stdout, stderr

The following problem occurs on .NET Framework v3.5. Don't know if it applies to v4*.

To capture stdout for some processes I've successfully used `p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;` and `p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;` and an event handler hooked to `p.StartInfo.OutputDataReceived+=...;`. Then I call `p.Start();` then `p.BeginOutputReadLine();` and then `p.WaitForExit();`

All is well so far. I get all stdout on the event handler, line by line, as expected.

I had to introduce a timeout instead of `WaitForExit()` because some processes unpredictably trigger requests for input at stdin (e.g. are you sure? [y/n]) leading to a deadlock where I wait forever and so do they.

The first thing I tried is changing to `while (!p.HasExited && DateTime.Now < timeoutmom) p.WaitForExit(200);` where `timeoutmoment` is 2 minutes after `proc.Start()`. This is when I ran into problems. Very consistently, the code works for calls that produce up to a few hundred lines of stdout but it breaks for one call that produces about 7500 lines. What happens is the `proc.WaitForExit(200);` thread exits the `while` when my `OutputDataReceived` event handler was called for only ~ 7300 lines (this number is again very consistent it varies by only +/- 1 between tests) and the handler is not called anymore for the rest of the stdout lines so I lose them.

<strike>Strangely, the problem doesn't appear if I avoid `WaitForExit(200)` and instead use `while (!p.HasExited && DateTime.Now < timeoutmom) System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);` (not shown in the code below).</strike> When I posted the question I was pretty sure the problem was avoided using `Sleep(1000)` but I was wrong. It worked a few dozen times like that and then it didn't, it started behaving just like when I checked `WaitForExit(200)`.

I now speculate that the reasons for this problem are (1) I take too long to process each `OutputDataReceived` callback. I noticed the problem was aggravated when I added a conditional breakpoint in the event handler which lengthened the method execution by a lot. I can now reproduce the problem by simply adding 3x Debug.WriteLines without the conditional breakpoint; PLUS (2) my context is somehow corrupted by me accessing `HasExited` / `WaitForExit(200)` before the system had a chance to perform all the callbacks on my event handler. I now do a blind `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000)` just after `p.Start()` and before accessing any `p.*` method and I get all the callbacks. When I used `WaitForExit()` it seemed I can take however much time I want to process every callback and I would still get them all.

Can someone make more sense of this?

Code:

```cs
    private int _execOsProc(
        ProcessStartInfo Psi
        , string SecInsensArgs
        , TextWriter ExtraStdOutAndErrTgt
        , bool OutputToExtraStdOutOnly
        )
    {
        var pr = new Process();
        pr.StartInfo = Psi;
        pr.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        pr.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = pr.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        pr.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        var ol = new DataReceivedEventHandler(this._stdOutDataReceived);
        var el = new DataReceivedEventHandler(this._stdErrDataReceived);
        pr.OutputDataReceived += ol;
        pr.ErrorDataReceived += el;
        try
        {
            __logger.Debug("Executing: \"" + pr.StartInfo.FileName + "\" " + SecInsensArgs);
            if (ExtraStdOutAndErrTgt == null)
            {
                this.__outputToExtraStdOutOnly = false;
            }
            else
            {
                this.__extraStdOutAndErrTgt = ExtraStdOutAndErrTgt;
                this.__outputToExtraStdOutOnly = OutputToExtraStdOutOnly;
            }
            pr.Start();
            pr.BeginOutputReadLine();
            pr.BeginErrorReadLine();
            var startmom = DateTime.Now;
            var timeoutmom = startmom.AddMinutes(2);
            while (!pr.HasExited && DateTime.Now < timeoutmom) pr.WaitForExit(200);
            pr.CancelOutputRead();
            pr.CancelErrorRead();
            if (pr.HasExited)
            {
                __logger.Debug("Execution finished with exit status code: " + pr.ExitCode);
                return pr.ExitCode;
            }
            else
            {
                __logger.Debug("Timeout while waiting for execution to finish");
                pr.Kill();
                return -100;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            pr.OutputDataReceived -= ol;
            pr.ErrorDataReceived -= el;
            if (this.__extraStdOutAndErrTgt != null)
            {
                this.__extraStdOutAndErrTgt = null;
                this.__outputToExtraStdOutOnly = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void _stdOutDataReceived(
        object sender
        , DataReceivedEventArgs e
        )
    {
        string rdata = string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data) ? "" : e.Data.Trim();
        if (!this.__outputToExtraStdOutOnly) __logger.Debug("SO: " + rdata);
        if (this.__extraStdOutAndErrTgt != null)
        {
            lock (this.__extraStdOutAndErrTgt)
            {
                try
                {
                    this.__extraStdOutAndErrTgt.WriteLine(rdata);
                    this.__extraStdOutAndErrTgt.Flush();
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    __logger.Warn(
                                "WARNING: Error detected but ignored during extra stream write"
                                    + " on SODR. Details: " + exc.Message
                                , exc
                                );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void _stdErrDataReceived(
        object sender
        , DataReceivedEventArgs e
        )
    {
        string rdata = string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data) ? "" : e.Data.Trim();
        if (!__outputToExtraStdOutOnly) __logger.Debug("SE: " + rdata);
        if (this.__extraStdOutAndErrTgt != null)
        {
            lock (this.__extraStdOutAndErrTgt)
            {
                try
                {
                    this.__extraStdOutAndErrTgt.WriteLine(rdata);
                    this.__extraStdOutAndErrTgt.Flush();
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    __logger.Warn(
                                "WARNING: Error detected but ignored during extra stream write"
                                    + " on SEDR. Details: " + exc.Message
                                , exc
                                );
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it will solve the problem, but it is too long to post it in the comment.

MSDN says about [Process.HasExited](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited(v=vs.110).aspx):

> When standard output has been redirected to asynchronous event
>   handlers, it is possible that output processing will not have
>   completed when this property returns true. To ensure that asynchronous
>   event handling has been completed, call the WaitForExit() overload
>   that takes no parameter before checking HasExited.

and about [WaitForExit()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This overload ensures that all processing has been completed,
>   including the handling of asynchronous events for redirected standard
>   output. You should use this overload after a call to the
>   WaitForExit(Int32) overload when standard output has been redirected
>   to asynchronous event handlers.

It indicates, that call to WaitForExit() **with no parameters** should solve the problem. Something like:

```
var startmom = DateTime.Now;
var timeoutmom = startmom.AddMinutes(2);
while (!pr.HasExited && DateTime.Now < timeoutmom)
    pr.WaitForExit(200);

if (pr.HasExited)
{
    WaitForExit();//Ensure that redirected output buffers are flushed

    pr.CancelOutputRead();
    pr.CancelErrorRead();

    __logger.Debug("Execution finished with exit status code: " + pr.ExitCode);
    return pr.ExitCode;
}
else
{
    pr.CancelOutputRead();
    pr.CancelErrorRead();

    __logger.Debug("Timeout while waiting for execution to finish");

    pr.Kill();
    return -100;
}
```

Comment: Jesus! I can't f*** believe this... I followed the docs for v3.5 where this info has not been backported. It fits the description of my problem perfectly. I'll try it out and come back with a comment. The big question seems to be if the final WaitForExit() really does flush the buffers after HasExited becomes true. A big Thank You!

Comment: Maybe behaviour in .NET 3.5 was different and WaitForExit() call was not neccessary - for example behaviour of "WaitForExit(-1)" has changed too after .NET 3.5. Unfortunately MSDN does not explicitly describe behaviour of WaitForExit() after HasExited==true, so you can just hope it will work.